# how to print logback internal errors and status logs?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am using logback api and have a logback.xml in my classpath which looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configuration scan="true">

    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL> 
    </contextListener>
    <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" name="STDOUT">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern> 
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender" name="FILE">
        <file>/${path}/logs/application.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/${path}/logs/application.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern> 
        </encoder>
    </appender>

<!--  ~~~ PERFORMANCE TRACKING LOGGER CONFIGURATION (USING PERF4J) || END ||~~~ 
  --> 
    <logger name="com.nucleus">
        <level value="DEBUG"/> 
        <!-- <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />  --> 
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/> 
    </logger>
    <logger level="DEBUG" name="org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction"/> 
    <logger level="DEBUG" name="org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager"/> 
    <logger level="DEBUG" name="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"/> 
    <!-- <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>  -->

</configuration>
```

Now the rollback that i have implemented is not working in the production environment only. I wish to debug the same and hence want to put a trace for this logback api. Can anyone suggest what i might be doing wrong or what should i do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

From [Logback 1.0.4](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-527) you can use system property `-Dlogback.debug=true` to enable debugging of your Logback setup which will allow you to debug your configuration.